# Fedora 18 : install input method

Tags: fedora, input-method, ibus

I'm using Fedora 18. I choose ibus in input method selector. In ibus, I choose preference to change input method. But I just see english-english method. I cannot choose input method for another language.(there is a dropbox, but all language is blur, but english). So, I don't know how to choose another language. (in my case is japanese and vietnamese).

I have tried a command when I google:

```
yum install scim-lang-japanese
```

but my terminal notice that this package does not exist.

Please teach me, how to add another input method for my language in ibus.

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `ibus-anthy` and `ibus-unikey` for those two languages so:

```
yum install ibus-anthy ibus-unikey
```

To set IBUS up follow these Fedora 17 guides (it should be pretty much the same thing in Fedora 18):

[japanese](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2012/06/08/japanese-input-on-fedora-17-linux-beefy-miracle-gnome-3/) , [vietnamese](http://cauhoi.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/basic-setup-steps-for-ibus-on-fedora-17-beefy-miracle/).